# Change detection in Angular SPA

Tags: angular, single-page-application

Consider the following very simplistic Angular SPA with the following components' tree structure:

```
        A
       / \
      B   C
```

**B, C** are the two pages of our SPA. Since **B** and **C** (their templates) can never be shown at the same time, my understanding is `there is no reason to trigger change detection` in **C** when there is model changing in **B** and vice versa. As to be more clear, e.g. even if the changes in **B** affect **C**, there won't be any problem since when C will be shown, a brand new DOM will be built which `will be aware of` the prior changes and reflect them.

`I'd appreciate your thoughts on the above`. Moreover, which is the best way to preclude e.g. **C** from change detection when changes apply to **B**?

Comment: You can preclude those changes by using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your component. It will only trigger CD if an input ref changes. So you can "push" a state object or observable to B, and as long as C doesn't use that same object or observable, it won't update.

Comment: This is not an answer to my question...

Comment: 'Page' is not a tech term. If it's a route, this should be stated. It's unclear what the problem is. You said that B and C don't coexist together. If changes in B shouldn't affect C, they just shouldn't share same set of data. If you have specific scenario that shows the behaviour you're describing, the best way to make the question clear is to provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: "there is no reason to trigger change detection" - it doesnt happen for components that are not present in the DOM. After they are gone, OnDestroy() fires and they are ready for garbage collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using routing to display B or C, and only one or the other is activated at any point, then the other does not exist in the DOM and therefore won't get any changes.

You can try this out by adding `console.log()` statements in your `ngOnInit` and `ngOnDestroy` methods. When you navigate to B, you'll get the ngOnInit. When you navigate to C, you'll get the `ngOnDestroy` for B and then `ngOnInit` for C.

So the answer to your question is that you don't have to do anything to preclude C from change detection when B is loaded.

Unless, of course, your layout is different than I assumed based on your question.

Here is a picture of one of my sample apps with Augury showing the component tree. Notice that the MovieEditComponent is not listed.

[image]

And here is another screen shot after I picked the Edit option. Now the MovieEditComponent is listed instead of the MovieDetailComponent.

[image]

Comment: My layout is what you assumed. From what you described, I understand that the component tree is dynamic and it includes only components existing in the DOM. So, in the above case if B is activated, C won't exist in the component tree. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If you add the log statements, you will be able to verify with your code.

Comment: I thought the component tree includes all the components no matter if they are part of the DOM or not. I did not know it is dynamic. How can I test with console.log if a component belongs to the component tree or not?

Comment: If you download Augury: https://augury.angular.io/ It adds an extension to Chrome that allows you to view the component tree. That may help.